# If $f$ is uniformly cont fcn on $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$, show $\exists!$ cont fcn $g$ on $[0,1]$ s.t. $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to just define $g(x)=f(x)$ on $\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$, and then define $g(x)=0$ for $ x \notin \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$?

If not, **any hints?**

Comment: Well, of course the thing you suggest won't work: consider a UC function $g$ on $[0,1]$ which is **not** zero on the irrationals, and extend $f=\left.g\right\rvert_{\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]}$. By the theorem you need to prove, the extension you chose is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments this won't work. For example take $f(x) =1$ on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.

But here's a hint:
$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, meaning for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there's a sequence $(q_n)_n$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} q_n\to x$.